# How to use one object in another class : PHP framework

Tags: php

This is my current system for a framework that I'm making:

I create an object upon a request to access a non-existing property, that has the name of an existing class through the `__get` function defined in the Core class. The Core class extends every class.

So it works like this:

```
class Someclass extends Core
{
    public function classmethod()
    {
        $this->otherclass->method();
    }
}
```

This works exactly how I want it to work. However, I have no idea (after a lot of frustration) how to edit/create properties of the object, using this system.

So something like this would't work.

```
$this->view->somevar = "newvalue"; // this doesn't work.
```

I guess it has to do something with the __set function, but I failed to find out.

I received the following suggestions how to tackle this problem:

Dependency injection, Namespaces, Singleton pattern.

I would love to see how to implement what I'm trying to do using one of these patterns.

I have no idea which to choose in order to achieve my simple problem: Use objects in other classes, so i don't need to put anything into __construct's parameters or using global variables.

I am using `__autoload.`

I hope i can tackle this problem with your help.

Comment: greetings, this and your other questions suggest you are making a framework with many similarities to codeigniter.  I realize this doesn't directly answer your question, but have you checked out codeigniter source code? https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/, code igniter is a very popular project and they do some of the Exacgt things you are asking in your questions.

Comment: @dm03514 Indeed, my goal is something similar to codeigniter, but simpler and lighter. I am hoping to learn a lot in the process. Thank you, I will check the source out! The problem is, I am in a great time shortage, that is the reason of me asking these questions.

Comment: @Rasteril, why wouldn't this: `$this->view->somevar = "newvalue";` work?

Comment: _I guess it has to do something with the `__set` function_ .. well you guessed right, I don't see any implementation code of the classes you are calling, would be helpful to see how you implemented the `__set` method and/or how it gets inherited.

Comment: @Rasteril you could also take a look at [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), a PHP micro-framework with encompasses some newer PHP development concepts

Comment: @Jeffrey I honestly have no idea. This is the code for the core function: https://github.com/Wolfard/AndroidPortal/blob/master/application/library/core.php ... On a call to an inaccessible property, a class instance is created. i don't know why I can't add stuff to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the architecture you're attempting is extremly bad. Aparently you are using "magic" to create objects attached as properties to other objects. Which is bad, because if you use _*get/*_set, you will end up in problems sooner rather than later. Also extending from a common parent is a bad thing because it generates huge inheritance trees, and it allows most of the objects to have more than one responsability.

Before starting a framework, you might want to look over: [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Now coming back to your question, if you use __get for getting a value, you can as well use __set for setting a value.

__construct method is there in order to allow you to initialize the object with all the data it needs in order to fulfill his sole purpose. Avoiding the __construct is kinda stupid, and defeats the purpose. You might want to pay attention to the D in SOLID in order to see what Dependency Inversion really is and to understand it.

Using __set loses completely the ability to typehint interfaces and so on. Therefore the code can become really buggy and ijcredibly hard to follow, since the flow is not so well defined, and the allocation is done in the back via magic. Also i can come up with 1 million other reason for which the architecture you are trying to use is wrong, but i will leave that for another time.

Comment: I wanted to create a light framework for my project, but this convinced me. I will be better off learning Codeigniter. There are just so many things, that am doing wrong, not only in this piece of code. However, it was a good learning experience.

Comment: Do not underestimate the experience of learning creating or attempting to create your own framework. You should still keep this as a side project. Understanding why the decisions you are taking are wrong is a huge step in understanding larger concepts. I would still go on with this, and see what problems you hit in the future. It will help you alot.

Comment: PS: If you want to build a application and want to use a already existing framework, you should consider all your options: Codeigniter, Cake (none of them are my favorites at the moment), symfony 2 (really good framework, based on solid concepts), silex (microframework based on s2 components, excellent for apis/rest interfaces), laravel, zend framework (not my choice, but huge array of components) etc. Asess what are your requirements and choose accordingly :)

Comment: I finally settled for Codeigniter, because it has a lot of good documentation and tutorials on the internet. I will not underestimate the learning experience, you are absolutely right. Thank you for your help.